# Text over Image using FFMPEG library on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Good day fellows.
I am trying to add a text over an image using this ffmpeg command

```
String exe = " -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/test1.jpg -vf drawtext=text='Test Text':fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=1002:y=100: " + file.getAbsolutePath();
```

But unfortunately I meet this error,

```
Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/test1.jpg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8264 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x1280, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xa38921b0] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xedd90500] Error initializing filter 'drawtext'[AVFilterGraph @ 0xedd90500]  with args 'text=Test Text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=1002:y=100:'[AVFilterGraph @ 0xedd90500] 
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Does someone had the same error as I have? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple and faster solution to this problem using Canvas on Android instead of using ffmpeg library.

Here is my code solution:

```
    ImageView mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);

    Bitmap.Config config = bm.getConfig();
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(newImage);
    c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setTextSize(150);

    c.drawText("Testare hai noroc",  bm.getWidth()/3, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(newImage);

    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/",System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg");

    try {
        newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope this solution will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message that you need to focus on (FFmpeg's error logs are sometimes misleading):

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xa38921b0] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
```

And this happened because you did not specify the font, and the default font "Sans" couldn't be found on your system. So, you need to specify one explicitly.

Here is [a link to the Android font resources reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource),
and [the first example in FFmpeg `drawtext` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-62) illustrates how to specify a font file.

(I'm not an Android dev, so hopefully you can figure it out from these links.)